# flutter_tools folder generation in local temp folders

Tags: flutter, temp

Whenever I run a newly created flutter project, a flutter_tools folder is generated on my AppData/Local/Temp folder that does not go away and I have to delete it manually. My main problem is that over the time, since when running or debugging an app, I will do many re-runs, these folders accumulate over time and happen to have a cumulative size of 100 GB, anyone else facing the same problem?

Comment: Why you use this flutter_tools in your project ?

Comment: I don't, it is generated automatically each time I ran a flutter project

Comment: That's not true, you added this flutter_tools in pubspec.yaml, and this library use in your project please check it and tell me.

Comment: There is no flutter_tools per se in my pubspec.yaml, and I use multiple packages since it's a big project. Could it be that some package uses this flutter_tools you mention? I believe that this is not a problem of packages but compilation (something to do with dev_tools when launching on chrome since the files are on the temp folder and are being generated each time the programm starts).

Comment: Definitely so, this package used in your project, maybe other packages use that, you must find it and fix it.

Comment: Each of these folder has an app.dill file inside, are you certain that this is a package issue and not a windows platform one? How exactly does it generate these through the package, please enlighten me.